# What is better iteration in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I got the result I was looking for. However, I suppose that there are a couple of ways to refactor my code below with pandas library.

code is simple. through 2012 - 2021, I rewrote my data from '1'(value of each year) to age of the year.

df:

| sex | age | siblings | payment | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 0 | ¥80,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 14 | 1 | ¥400,000 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 13 | 2 | ¥480,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 14 | 0 | ¥240,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 17 | 2 | ¥160,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 15 | 1 | ¥280,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 11 | 0 | ¥260,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  age = int(row['age'])
  for col_idx, col_value in enumerate(row[4:]):
    if col_value == 1:
      age += 1
      df.iloc[index, col_idx + 4] = age
```

df:

| sex | age | siblings | payment | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 9 | 0 | ¥80,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 13 | 1 | ¥400,000 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 12 | 2 | ¥480,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 | 14 | 15 |  |
| 0 | 13 | 0 | ¥240,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 14 | 15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 16 | 2 | ¥160,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 14 | 1 | ¥280,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |  |
| 0 | 10 | 0 | ¥260,000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 11 | 0 |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df_out = df.loc[:, "2012":].cumsum(axis=1).add(df["age"] - 1, axis=0)
df_out[df.loc[:, "2012":].eq(0)] = 0

df_out = pd.concat([df[["sex", "age", "siblings", "payment"]], df_out], axis=1)
# df_out["age"] -= 1 # if you need to substract 1 from age
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   sex  age  siblings   payment  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019  2020  2021
0    0   10         0   ¥80,000     0     0     0     0     0    10    11    12     0     0
1    1   14         1  ¥400,000    14    15    16    17     0     0     0     0     0     0
2    1   13         2  ¥480,000     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    13    14    15
3    0   14         0  ¥240,000     0     0     0     0    14    15     0     0     0     0
4    1   17         2  ¥160,000     0     0     0     0     0    17    18    19     0     0
5    1   15         1  ¥280,000     0     0     0     0     0    15    16    17    18    19
6    0   11         0  ¥260,000     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    11     0
```

Comment: it gave me an error: 
KeyError: '2012'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: '2012'

Comment: I edited. sorry. is this because column name '2012' is not pure string?

Comment: @t0j1 Could be. You can replace `df.loc[:, "2012":]` for `df.iloc[:, 4:]` and it should work.

Comment: It works. Simple code without `for` iteration looks pretty smart. very impressive.